# XMLHttpRequest cannot load from other site

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am facing this error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://xyz.com/test/points?domain=test.com&id=100. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin ('https://sourcerequest.com') is therefore not allowed access.
```

Even i have set the header like this:

```
  headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = request.headers["HTTP_ORIGIN"]
  headers['Access-Control-Expose-Headers'] = 'ETag'
  headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD'
  headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = '*,x-requested-with,Content-Type,If-Modified-Since,If-None-Match,Auth-User-Token'
  headers['Access-Control-Max-Age'] = '86400'
  headers['Access-Control-Allow-Credentials'] = 'true'
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
 headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
```

Comment: Where are you setting the headers? In a `before_filter`?